# Error initializing default drive: 'Either the target name is incorrect or.....'

Tags: active-directory, powershell

I'm trying to write a small Powershell script.

I only have this in my code:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
```

I get this error/warning:

> WARNING: Error initializing default drive: 'Either the target name is
>   incorrect or the server has rejected the client credentials.'.

I searched for an answer and found possible solutions, but they didn't work.

I'm using Windows 10.

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: You should list what you have tried. Then possible answers can exclude what didn't work, and those failed attempts may lead to the correct solution.

Answer (score 1):

Is the Windows 10 system part of a domain? When you load this module by default, it attempts to look at your service records, find an efficiently located domain controller and map it to the PSDrive "AD:\" so that you can navigate it within powershell and review records.

It is possible to disable this:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/adpowershell/2010/04/12/disable-loading-the-default-drive-ad-during-import-module/

Answer (score 1):

For some reason I solved it by reinstalling RSAT again.